# DSpace 5.4 Metadata Import Error UTF-8 Unknown Element in Heading: id

Tags: dspace

I have a problem in importing UTF-8 encoded files in DSPace 5.4. If the same file is encoded with ASCII, the entire thing is getting imported, however, if I encode in UTF-8 and try to import, it fails. It fails in all the 3 ways to import metadata, specific error messages are:

Import Metadata (GUI) - Unknown metadata element in heading: id

Batch Import (GUI) - After importing, when I go to MyDSPACE and try to see the imported items in Batch Imports, the one with Unicode Text is not displayed and generating "Internal System Error"

CLI Import at Server - Bad Metadata Declaration in row 1: id

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Can you give us the first line or two of your file (with fake data that still triggers the problem, if necessary)?

Comment: Which application are you using to save/encode the file? Google Sheets and Open Refine have been working great for me after a lot of misery/mystery with other editors.

Comment: Bram: Tried both MS Excel and LibreOffice.

Comment: please share your file, I suspect that something is wrong with the first row, where the headers are declared.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, but I solved it with Notepad++, where I have saved my csv file with encoding to "UTF-8 without BOM" in main menu.
My CSV file looks same, but error message with wrong ID dissappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely late response, but I came to this post after having a similar issue. Deleting the blank, extra sheet in my workbook solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am also responding very late, but I successfully used the solution from [Matúš Formanek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6028082/mat%c3%ba%c5%a1-formanek): change the  encoding of the CSV file.

In my copy of Notepad++, the Encoding menu has no "UTF-8 without BOM" option. It has both "Encode in UTF-8" and "Convert to UTF-8". Both options worked for me.

I also tried deleting the empty sheet in my workbook in Excel before saving to the UTF-8 CSV file. That did not make any difference.

All of this is probably specific to one's environment. I'm using: an Atmire-customized instance of DSpace 5.6; Excel desktop build 1902 from Office 365; Notepad++ 7.7.1 64-bit.